# OpenLayers: adding a loading indicator for WMS requests

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, loading

I'm new to Openlayers and GIS in general. I have a WMS request followed by the addLayer method, and surrounded by the addition and deletion of a 'loading' class to an HTML element:

```js
$(toggle).parent('div').first().addClass('loading');
Map.currentOverlay = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(name, Constants.webServices.wms, {
    format: 'image/png',
    tiled: false,
    transparent:true
  }, {
    singleTile:true,
    ratio:1,
    getURL: Projection.getDefaultOverlayUrl 
  });
}
if (Map.currentOverlay != null) {
  Map.currentOverlay.initialZoom = map.zoom;
  Map.currentOverlay.isBaseLayer = false;
  Map.currentOverlay.visibility = true;
  Map.currentOverlay.events.on({moveend: Map.__onZoomUpdate});
  map.addLayer(Map.currentOverlay);
  $(toggle).parent('div').first().removeClass('loading');
```

My goal is to add a loading gif in a dialog window (with CSS) while the layer is not displayed yet. According to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569847/when-does-openlayers-wms-physically-call-the-remote-server the request is done in the addLayer method. But it seems asynchronous: the class 'loading' is added and removed straight away, while the map is not yet displayed.
Can I add a callback or something similar to addLayer ? If not, how do I do?

NB: I didn't produce the above code, I just added the "loading" behaviour. Do not hesitate to tell me if something seems wrong with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the loadstart and loadend events on the layer to handle this. This example (http://openlayers.org/dev/tests/manual/loadend.html) shows the basics of how to get it working.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the following example useful: 
http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/layerLoadMonitoring.html

Essentialy, the OpenLayers API gives you the layer events 'loadstart', 'loadend' and 'tileloaded'. When you register these events, you can 'hook' functions that, for example, can show a loading indicator.